# Is it pointless to concatenate C-style cast operations?

Tags: c++, casting

At work I found this code in my codebase, where chars are casted twice:

```
constexpr unsigned int foo(char ch0, char ch1, char ch2, char ch3)
{
    return   ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)(ch0) 
           | ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)(ch1) << 8)
           | ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)(ch2) << 16) 
           | ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)(ch3) << 24))
           ;
}
```

Wouldn't one cast to `unsigned int` be sufficient?
And in that case better make it a `static_cast<unsigned_int>`?

Comment: Fun fact: The only thing making this C++ is `constexpr`. The rest is C style casts.

Comment: Hint: `char` is a signed type on many platforms.  Consider what happens when `ch0` is `-1`.

Comment: Unrelated: Try to avoid the C-Style casts. They ignore all common sense and will force the conversion no matter how bad an idea. A `static_cast` is a better choice here because if you do screw up, the compiler can catch the mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  Consider if one of the `char`'s has the value of `-1`.  When you do

```
(unsigned int)(unsigned char)-1
```

you get `255` for a 8 bit `char` since you first do the conversion modulo `2^8`.  If you instead used

```
(unsigned int)-1
```

then you would get `4294967295` for a 32 bit `int` since you are now doing the conversion modulo `2^32`.

---

So the first cast guarantees the result will be representable in 8 bits, or whatever the actual size a char is, and then the second cast is to promote it to a wider type.

---

You can get rid of the casts to `unsigned char` if you chnage the function parameters to it like

```
constexpr unsigned int foo(unsigned char ch0, unsigned char ch1, 
                           unsigned char ch2, unsigned char ch3)
{
    return   static_cast<unsigned int>(ch0) 
           | static_cast<unsigned int>(ch1) << 8)
           | static_cast<unsigned int>(ch2) << 16) 
           | static_cast<unsigned int>(ch3) << 24))
           ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought about that. In my head casting char to int would've preserved the 8-bit value but I can see that would not have been the case.

Comment: @Turambar yes, when extending a smaller numeric type to a larger numeric type, you have to pay attention to **sign-extension** vs **zero-extension**. This kind of code requires zero-extension.